# PHP: Filtering and posting a text file

Tags: php, csv, text-files, filtering

I have a text file that contains a persons surname, address, time of accident and reason of accident separated by a white space in a line. I need to filter this file by only the people that have called in at least two times for the same reason and echo it.
I'm fairly new to PHP so I would like a simple way. :)
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I haven't tried anything since I have no clue how to even filter file contents.

```
$data = array($_POST['surname'], $_POST['address'], $_POST['time'], $_POST['reason']);
$info = implode("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $data)
$info .= "\r\n";
serialize($info);
file_put_contents("data.txt", $info, FILE_APPEND);
serialize($info);
```

This is how I wrote it into a file.
I imploded the file because I needed to make them separated by 3 white spaces, but it no longer matters so I can just keep the array.

The expected output should be something like this:

```
Surname   Address   Time   Reason
Adams   Railroad 5   13:20   Heart Attack
Adams   Railroad 5   23:35   Heart Attack
```

It would only need to repeat the same people that have matching Surnames and Reasons.

Comment: Have you tried something? Please show your attempts. Also include an example of your input file and your expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

your text file contains string, entries seprated by line brakes and values by three spaces (actually html coded spaces).

Here we read whole txt file in,(some could do this [line](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) by line):

```
$whole_string = file_get_contents('data.txt');
```

So firstly we get each line:

```
$entries = explode('\n',$whole_string);
```

Then value arrays are pushed:

```
$whole_ar = array();
foreach($entries as $e){
   $whole_ar[] = explode('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',$e);
}//if 3 spaces in file are in html
```

We get:

```
array(
    array(
    'name','date','etc..'
    ),
    array(
    'name2','date','etc..'
    ),
    array(
    'name2','date','etc..'
    )
)
```

You could store array in php file, for later to `include('data.php');` like so:

```
$file = '<?php $whole_ar='.var_export($whole_ar, TRUE)."; ?>";
file_put_contents('data.php', $file);
```

Main answer on how to parse this array to target copies is iteritating [or](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$answer = array_unique(array_diff_assoc($whole_ar, array_unique( $whole_ar)));
```

---

As I understand, you get information like this [string](https://php.net/language.types.string) when user calls in:

```
$newest = "Huchinson Estonia Tallin Geo street 13 2015.12.02 13:44 Gas leak"
```

You have this string in variable, like stated above.
Then you could **explode** string by space characters: `$data = explode(" ",$newest);` which gives you an array with number of values. First value will be a surname and last will be reason of accident.

Parse them out of array like this: `echo $data[0];//this will be surname` and `echo end($data);//this will be accident type`

Instead of echo you can assign these values to variables and look up if this surname AND accident is present in your database:

```
if($saved_before == $data[0].end($data)){
   echo "we are working on ".end($data).", be patient, dear ".$data[0];
}
```

p.s. dot (.) is for concatenating strings

Comment: The answer doesn't seem to work on multidimensional arrays, I get a notice that "Array to string conversion", though your post did help me a lot.

Comment: the variable `$newest` is an array, to see how it looks, do the `echo('<pre>');print_r($newest);echo('</pre>');` I suppose it will contain arrays of arrays of values (2dimension). I just realized $newest will contain duplicate values on entries where not only surname and accident are identical, but where whole array is identical. Thou sorry, i didn't tested my post yet. Maybe an `array_column` function might come in handy for you at parsing out duplicate surname and accident entries. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well the txt file is a csv file that uses a space as the delimenter of the columns. So use use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function to load columns of each row. Specify the blank space as the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

That should get you started:

```
function parseIt($line) { return str_getcsv($line, "   "); }
$all = array_map('parseIt', file('yourfile.txt'));
$names = array();
foreach ($all as $row) { 
    $uniqkey = $row[0].$row[3];
    if (isset($names[$uniqkey])) {
        echo implode(" ",$row);
        $names[$uniqkey]++;
    } else {
        $names[$uniqkey] = 1;
    }
}
```

I noticed in your file writing code you use a delimiter of 3 white spaces so I used it in the example - you can set it to whatever you want in the `str_getcsv(line, delimiter)`

Explanation:

- Lines 1,2 - `file()` will read the file into an array that are passed through the function `parseIt()` this function will parse the line and return an array of the line value.
- Line 3 - The array `$names` will act our memory, at the end it will hold all names + reason as keys and the value will be the counter of occurrences.
- Line 4... - Loops through `$all` checks if the key exists in `$names` if it does it prints the row and moves the counter otherwise sets a new key in `$names` and set its value to 1 (counter).